# How to retrieve From/Address value in SOAP header (in Java/SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot SOAP application using this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-soap-web-service Everything works like a charm so far.

**Task: I'd like to access the SOAP header.**

This is what I've done so far:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
    [..]
}
```

I can just extend this with `MessageContext`:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request, MessageContext messageContext) {
    [..]
}
```

This `MessageContext`  plus a little util method `fooBar` is supposed to access the SOAP header:

```
protected static String fooBar(final MessageContext messageContext) {
    SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSoapHeader();
    [...]
}
```

So far so good. This is what my SOAP message looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        [...]
        xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <soap:Header>
        [...]
        <wsa:From>
            <wsa:Address>http://from-endpoint</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:From>
        [...]
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        [...]
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to get the address in `<From><Address>`:  http://from-endpoint .. but now it starts to get awkward..

```
protected static String fooBar(final MessageContext messageContext) {
    SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSoapHeader();
    Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> soapHeaderElementIterator = soapHeader.examineAllHeaderElements();
    while (soapHeaderElementIterator.hasNext()) {
        SoapHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeaderElementIterator.next();
        if (soapHeaderElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("From")) {
 [...]
```

This works as expected, but this `SoapHeaderElement` is type [org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeaderElement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/soap/SoapHeaderElement.html) which gives me no options to access further child elements.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

...
...
...

✅ SOLUTION has been found - see comments

Comment: Now if only there would be an [`@SoapHeader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/ws/soap/SoapElement.html) annotation that you could use to map that. You can also use the `SoapHeader` interface/class to get the full header instead of the `MessageContext. But something like `@SoapHeader("{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"}From") SoapHeaderElement from` should do the trick. You can then extract the text from that element.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed I can use this:

`@SoapHeader("{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}From") SoapHeaderElement fromHeaderElement`

But by doing so I'm still not able to access the address. `getText` returns null.. which makes sense since there is not text - just another child element `Address` - and this `Address` is what I need :-)

Comment: I suspect the easiest way is to use the proper `AddressingVersion` in your code, I suspect the `Addressing10`. You can use the `getMessageAddressingProperties` to obtain all the headers for the `SoapMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help of [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)  I've found a solution:

```
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request, MessageContext messageContext) {
        Addressing10 addressing10 = new Addressing10();
        MessageAddressingProperties messageAddressingProperties = addressing10.getMessageAddressingProperties((SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest());
        URI address = messageAddressingProperties.getFrom().getAddress();
    }
```